# Best way to share data between Javascript and Sass in Rails?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

What is the best way to share data between Javascript and Sass?

The two options I see are:

1) Use something like `sass-json-vars` to be able to `@import` JSON files into Sass, then simply import the JSON into Javascript.

2) Use `.css.scss.erb` files the Rails asset pipeline, and in that CSS file import the JSON using the `json` Ruby gem, then simply import the JSON into Javascript.

Is one better than the other? Is there an even better option?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not quite sure I understand what kind of data you want to share, or why this would be necessary. Have you considered simply setting the dynamic properties with inline CSS in your views instead?

Let’s say you’ve got a bunch articles on a page, and each article has a dynamic background colour that’s set in the database, I think the best thing would be to create your article class with a sensible default background in SASS, and then override it in your erb views like this:

#### SASS

```
.article {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

#### ERB

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <article class="article" style="background-color: <%= article.background_colour %>">
    <%= article.title %>
  </article>
<% end %>
```